# VBA - Text Filter appearing in a Date Column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Date Column and I am trying to filter it in vba.

I just noticed that the column is providing only text filters in excel.

How can I change this to show me date filters.

what could be the problem behind this?

There are blanks in the column as well and I removed the blank and applied the date format for the column as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have dates in the column, or just text that looks like dates?  Temporarily change the column to `General` format and ensure that everything changes to look like a number - if it continues looking like dates then you have text in the column.

Comment: why was the answer provided removed. It actually worked. I want to mark that as an answer. They are all dates, just wrongly formatted.So when I did the text to columns functionality it started showing date filters.

Comment: Not sure whether this will actually ping @ChrisMoore but, if so, ... can you please undelete your answer.

Comment: Then let's vote to undelete it, idk how many votes it needs :d @YowE3K

Comment: @A.S.H I don't yet have the rep to vote to undelete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

- Change the Format of the Column from text to date.
- Do Text to Columns on the Required Column.

> Text to Columns recalculates the column format and enables the date filter for the Column.